# what's the correct default value for an r-value reference argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value, move-semantics, icc

Suppose I have a function that takes an r-value argument and I want to provide a default value, how do I correctly specify that? The following works fine with gcc 4.7.0, but fails
with icpc 13.0.1.

```
struct data {
  int _data[10];
  data() = default;
  data(data&&) = default;
  data(const data&) = default;
};
void func(data&& = data{});
```

icpc complains that

```
error: type name is not allowed
void func(data&& = data{});
                   ^
```

Is this correct? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Does icpc support universal initialization syntax here? Have you tried a value-initializer `data && = data()`?

Comment: @ecatmur indeed that works. so this seems a intel problem. The version 13.0.1 is supposed to be gcc 4.7.0 compatible, but this is not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that icpc 13.0.1 doesn't support universal-initialization syntax in default arguments.  This works:

```
void func(data&& = data());
                       ^^ value-initialization
```